# How to find customer details from table1 who have many contact no in table 2 in sql sever

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in SQL Server

table1 has CustomerID, CustomerName and table2 has CustomerID, Contact. Now I have to find the customer name and ID who have two contact numbers in table2.

I have written query, but it shows only ID of customer not name:

```
SELECT distinct tbl_Cust1.CustID, tbl_Cust1.CustName
    FROM tbl_Cust1 INNER JOIN
         tbl_Cust2 ON tbl_Cust1.CustID =tbl_Cust2.CustID
         and tbl_Cust2.CustID in (SELECT tbl_Cust2.CustID
                                   FROM  tbl_Cust2
                                   GROUP BY CustID
                                   HAVING (COUNT(*) = 2))
```

Comment: it seems to me that you have already answered your own question. Your query will give you all those who have 2 records of details in the other table. Otherwise, please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.CustID, t1.CustName
    FROM tbl_Cust1 t1 
    JOIN tbl_Cust2 t2 ON t1.CustID = t2.CustID
    GROUP BY CustID, t1.CustName 
    HAVING (COUNT(t2.Contact) = 2))
```